# segmentation fault (core dumped) error in converson code

Tags: c, coredump

I am newbie  to C programing and facing below segmentation fault for below code snippet.
`sample.txt` is used as a file input and below is the content of this file.

Below is the content of the `sample.txt` file-

> ```
>           1001:"field1":N
>           1001:"field2":B
>           1001:"field3":A
>           1001:"field4":D
>           1001:"field5":N
>           1001:"field6":N
> ```

This in my Code Snippet-

```
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_OID_LEN 128
#define MAX_FILE_NAME_LEN 128
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 80
#define MAXSTRINGSIZE 20
#define MAX_VALUE_LEN 128
int8_t* field[MAX_VALUE_LEN]={0,};     

int8_t* type[MAX_VALUE_LEN]={0,};
int8_t field_count=0;   
char * option(int8_t* type[MAX_VALUE_LEN], int8_t* field[MAX_VALUE_LEN])
{

int8_t i=0;
if(*type)
{
while(**type)
{
switch(**type)
{

case 'D':

printf("\nDateType");
printf("\nfield=%s",field[i]);
break;
case 'N':
printf("\nInteger");
printf("\nfield=%s",field[i]);
break;
case 'A':
printf("\nAscii");
printf("\nfield=%s",field[i]);

break;
case 'B':
printf("\nBinary");
printf("\nfield=%s",field[i]);

break;

default:
printf("\nDefault=%s",field[i]);
return *type;
//break;
}
*type++;
i++;
printf("\ni=%d",i);
}
printf("%s",field[i]);

}
return NULL;

//printf("%s",field[i]);
}


int main()
{
int8_t field_count=0;
        int8_t* data_field;
        int8_t* token;
        int8_t* ismp_field;
        int8_t *search = ":";
        FILE *fp;
        int8_t* filename = "sample.txt";
        fp = fopen ( filename, "r" );
        if( fp != NULL )
        {
                int8_t line [MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                while ( fgets ( line, sizeof (line), fp ) != NULL )
                {
                        token = strtok( line, search );
                        ismp_field = strtok( NULL, search );
                        data_field = strtok( NULL, "\n" );
                        if(ismp_field!=NULL)
                        {
                                field[field_count]=strdup(ismp_field);
                                printf("\nismp_field=%s\n", ismp_field);
                                type[field_count]=strdup(data_field);
                                printf("\ndata_value=%s\n",type[field_count]);
                                field_count++;
                        }
                }
                fclose ( fp );


}
char *val=option(type,field);
printf("%s",val);
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Build a version with debug information (add the `-g` flag to `gcc`) and run in a debugger. The debugger will stop when the crash happens, and at the location of the crash. The debugger will then be able to show you the function call stack, and even walk up the call stack so you can get to your code (if the crash isn't there already) and there you can examine the values of your variables.

Comment: At the very least, build with debug-info and run in a debugger and edit your question to include the function call stack. That way we will know where the crash happens and can help you narrow down the way to large code you posted, making it easier to find the root cause of the crash.

Comment: Until you have done that, there are a couple of things you should take not of. For example, the expression `*type++` might not do what you expect it to, as the compiler sees it as `*(type++)` and not `(*type)++`. Also, wht are you using pointer dereferencing instead of normal indexing? Like `type[X][Y]`? That will make the code *much* easier to understand, as well as it will make the code easier.

Comment: Here is the place where coredump is recieved:Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004008c0 in option (type=0x6014d0 <type+48>, field=0x6010a0 <field>) at converson.c:20
20 while(**type)

Comment: Referring how to debug by your own: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the dereferencing of `type` inside the `option` function, that's probably where your problem is. Because you declare it as an array of pointers, and each pointer is initialized to `NULL`, and then you dereference these `NULL` pointers, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and your crash.

Answer (score 0):

The option function needs to changed. Find the fix in below

```
char * option(int8_t* type[MAX_VALUE_LEN], int8_t* field[MAX_VALUE_LEN])
{

int8_t i=0;
if(*type)
{
while(*type && **type) //Fix
{
switch(**type)
{

case 'D':

printf("\nDateType");
printf("\nfield=%s",field[i]);
break;
case 'N':
printf("\nInteger");
printf("\nfield=%s",field[i]);
break;
case 'A':
printf("\nAscii");
printf("\nfield=%s",field[i]);

break;
case 'B':
printf("\nBinary");
printf("\nfield=%s",field[i]);

break;

default:
printf("\nDefault=%s",field[i]);
return *type;
//break;
}
*type++;
i++;
printf("\ni=%d",i);
}
printf("%s",field[i]);

}
```

The variable **type** is capable of holding 128 pointers, but all are not used in this case. So check NULL before using the pointer, it is always good practice

Comment: Thanks mahendiran for update . It is functional now.